# Can one create a 64bit hash from multiple 32bit hashes?

Tags: hash

If I create a 64bit hash by concatenating a 32bit hash of the odd bytes of a string with a 32bit hash of the even bytes of a string, how does that compare to a proper 64bit hash of the full string?

I have the FNV-1a hash in mind, but it's really a general question about hash strength.

Comment: Those hashes will be completely different. Also FNV-1 can be 64bit.

Comment: Let's say I'm restricted to only use a 32bit FNV-1a. I'm not saying it would be the equivalent of a 64bit FNV-1a, I just want to know, in comparison to a true 64bit FNV-1a, how does my chance of collision change?

Comment: Well, this is not a cryptographic hash. So I wouldn't rely on collision resistance at all.

Comment: Well thanks for your opinion on that, but it sounds like you don't know the answer to my question.